# C# How to use multiple interface implementations

Tags: c#, dynamic, interface, instantiation

I have 2 separate Interface Implementations and based on a setting I have stored in my database I want to use either one (create object of specific impl class and execute methods).

So,

If setting = 1 then use Interface Implementation 1
Else use Interface Implementation 2

What is the best way to do this?  Is there anyway to dynamically instantiate an object of the correct interface implementation based on a variable value?

Comment: We'll need more background to the problem; it looks like you're trying to find a solution to the wrong problem. What will the two interfaces do? What will they be used for? Why do you need to use two separate interfaces?

Comment: @thecoop it seems like a normal situation for me !

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [factory design pattern](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory).

Comment: which hides an if-else or switch - but this is acceptable at initialization time. For everything afterwards you should rely on polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll want to have a look at the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

In essence, you delegate the creation of the actual object to another object (called the factory).  When asked for an instance of the object, the factory would look at the database value and create the appropriate instance.